# have text longer than a vim windows displayed on several lines

Tags: vimrc, wrapping, wrap

I'm trying to have text longer than a vim windows displayed on several lines. For this, I tried to follow the advice of [this blog](https://agilesysadmin.net/how-to-manage-long-lines-in-vim/) by entering `set wrap`  in the `.vimrc` file but nothing changes and the text is still longer than the window width. Is there another function in my `.vimrc` file that desables it. Here is the `.vimrc` file:

```
" Set the line number

set clipboard=unnamed
set modeline
set hlsearch
set ruler
set laststatus=2
set statusline+=%F
set title
set shiftwidth=0
set autoindent
set smartindent
set ignorecase
set smartcase
" set number relativenumber
set nolist
set number 
set spelllang=en
set spell
set expandtab " define the size of indentation 
set shiftwidth=4 " define the size of indentation

set wrap "wrap lines longer than the screen's width " https://agilesysadmin.net/how-to-manage-long-lines-in-vim/

" setlocal foldmethod=syntax

" NERDtree https://shapeshed.com/vim-netrw/
let g:netrw_banner = 0
let g:netrw_liststyle = 3
let g:netrw_browse_split = 4
let g:netrw_altv = 1
let g:netrw_winsize = 25
"augroup ProjectDrawer
"  autocmd!
"  autocmd VimEnter * :Vexplore
"augroup END

xnoremap p pgvy " keep copied item in clipoard even after command p

" set syntax (e.g. color highlighting in code)
" syntax enable 
syntax on
" colorscheme distinguished
colorscheme onedark
" colorscheme desert
" colorscheme delek
" colorscheme blue
" colorscheme darkblue
" colorscheme default
" colorscheme delek
" colorscheme desert
" colorscheme elflord
" colorscheme evening
" colorscheme koehler
" colorscheme morning
" colorscheme murphy
" colorscheme pablo
" colorscheme peachpuff
" colorscheme ron
" colorscheme shine
" colorscheme slate
" colorscheme torte
" colorscheme zellner

hi Normal guibg=NONE ctermbg=NONE

" set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
" filetype off                  " required

" automatically close brackets, parenthesis etc...
" inoremap " ""<left>
" inoremap ' ''<left>
" inoremap ( ()<left>
" inoremap [ []<left>
" inoremap { {}<left>
" inoremap {<CR> {<CR>}<ESC>O
" inoremap {;<CR> {<CR>};<ESC>O

call plug#begin()

Plug 'dag/vim-fish'

call plug#end()

filetype plugin on
filetype plugin indent on  " optional!
"syntax enable
highlight LineNr ctermfg=grey

"set nocompatible
"filetype off
"
"set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle/
"call vundle#rc()
"
"Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'
"Bundle 'dag/vim-fish'
"
"filetype plugin indent on    " required
"highlight LineNr ctermfg=grey

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

Plugin 'JuliaEditorSupport/julia-vim'
Plugin 'lervag/vimtex'

" A Vim Plugin for Lively Previewing LaTeX PDF Output
Plugin 'xuhdev/vim-latex-live-preview'
let g:livepreview_previewer = 'evince'
let g:tex_flavor='latex'
" let g:livepreview_previewer = 'open -a Preview'
" autocmd Filetype tex setl updatetime=700 

"let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat='pdf'

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required

" call plug#begin(g:plugged_home)
"     " other plugins...
"     " --------- adding the following three plugins for Latex ---------
"     Plug 'lervag/vimtex'
"     Plug 'Konfekt/FastFold'
"     Plug 'matze/vim-tex-fold'
"     " other plugins...
" call plug#end()

" Autocomplete for Python
Plugin 'davidhalter/jedi-vim'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The help [`:h 'wrap'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27wrap%27) tells us that the option is local to a window. So setting it up in your vimrc will not affect the windows you will open while using vim.

You have several solutions then:

- Manually using `:set wrap` on windows where you need the option enabled.
- Using an autocommand to set the option everywhere:

  ```
  augroup wrap
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufWinEnter * setlocal wrap
  augroup END
  ```
- Using a ftplugin to set the option for the filetypes you need. For example for markdown files create `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/markdown.vim` and put `setlocal wrap` in it.

See [`:h autocmd`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#autocmd), [`:h autocmd-events`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#autocmd-events) and [`:h ftplugin`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#ftplugin)

Comment: Sorry if I was a bit to quick for the feedback @statox: `:set wrap` does indeed work for each new window, but the general command (which is what I'm looking for) `augroup wrap
  autocmd!
  autocmd WinEnter * setlocal wrap
augroup END` does not seem to work...

Comment: @ecjb My bad I used the wrong autocommand event, it's `BufWinEnter` not `WinEnter`

Comment: many thanks @statox. Now it works!